# Radar like scan based on current locations

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am developeing an app , that scans certain distance and displays the all the users with that application on radar like map .

I am getting a list of latitudes and longitudes from an api , now i need the user tp apperar on center of radar and others in respective direction and distance .

Can i achieve this using mapview ?

Or is there any better way ?

Please suggest me a good to handle this issue .

I have not started coding yet so , could not provide any starup .

Plz help thanks !

Comment: Well I think you can achieve it using MKMapView.

Comment: Can you give some idea

Answer (score 0):

`MKMapView` has the cunningly named method:

```
setUserTrackingMode:animated:
```

As the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html) states:

> Setting the tracking mode to MKUserTrackingModeFollow or MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading causes the map view to center the map on that location and begin tracking the user’s location